# Not returning html page for viewing - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

error message --> **The view orders.views.charge didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.** any reason why my charge.html isn't working?

**views,py**

```
import time 
import stripe

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='eur',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
            )
        template = "orders/charge.html"
        return render(request, template)
```

charge.html

```
{% extends "fuisce/base.html" %}


{% block content %}

  <div class="container mt-5 text-center">
    <h2 class="text-center">Thanks, you for your Orders</h2>
    <a href="/my-orders" class="btn btn-success">My Orders</a>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from orders import views as order_views
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('checkout/', order_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('charge/', order_views.charge, name='charge'),
    path('orders/', order_views.orders, name='user_orders'),
    path('add_user_address/', user_views.add_user_address, name='add_user_address'),
]
```

Comment: That will indeed happen if you make a GET request to your `charge` view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry I don't follow what you're saying?

Comment: what if `request.method` is *not* `'POST'`, but `'GET'`, then the `if` will not be triggered, and hence the function will indeed return `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the returning code from your view outside the if condition if you want it to return on `GET` requests.

```
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='eur',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
            )
    template = "orders/charge.html"
    return render(request, template)
```